# How can I have connection to 0.0.0.0 port 5000?

Tags: python, linux, flask

I'm Creating an endpoint that retrieves the number of each objects by type. when I execute the code with:

`curl -X GET http://0.0.0.0:5000/api/v1/stats`

it says:

`curl: (7) Failed to connect to 0.0.0.0 port 5000: Connection refused`

I've been trying to see if I have a config file, checked my listed ports, Google on how to change/activate the port, and still haven't found something.

This is my full code:

````
''' module that makes this an app '''

from flask import Flask, abort, jsonify
from models import storage
from api.v1.views import app_views
from os import getenv
app = Flask(__name__)


app.register_blueprint(app_views)


@app.teardown_appcontext
def close(self):
    ''' method that close the yes '''
    storage.close()


@app.errorhandler(404)
def invalid_route(e):
    return jsonify({"error": "Not found"}), 404


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host=getenv("HBNB_API_HOST", "0.0.0.0"),
            port=int(getenv("HBNB_API_PORT", "5000")), threaded=True)```
````

Comment: Why are you trying to connect to `0.0.0.0`? That's not an address that's going to mean anything useful. When you *bind* to address `0.0.0.0` that means "listen on all available addresses", so just pick an address on your host (e.g., `127.0.0.1`) and use that in your `curl` command.

Comment: just check echo $HBNB_API_PORT if there is another port configured

Comment: @larsks: `0.0.0.0` could be a valid target. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/419880/connecting-to-ip-0-0-0-0-succeeds-how-why

Comment: That linked answer basically reads, "it's invalid and you're lucky that it even works".

Answer (score 0):

Your code is completely right, you are not sending the request to the right host.

Your flask server is bound to `0.0.0.0`, which means that your server will be bound to the default address (either `localhost` or your actual IP address)

This should be fine:
`curl -X GET http://localhost:5000/api/v1/stats`

Answer (score 0):

I used an executable command like this:

`HBNB_MYSQL_USER=hbnb_dev HBNB_MYSQL_PWD=hbnb_dev_pwd HBNB_MYSQL_HOST=localhost HBNB_MYSQL_DB=hbnb_dev_db HBNB_TYPE_STORAGE=db HBNB_API_HOST=0.0.0.0 HBNB_API_PORT=5000 sudo python3 -m api.v1.app`

but I forgot to add `sudo` before `python3`. Then you should open a new terminal and execute the curl command. THANKS